# Returning std::pair versus passing by non-const reference

Tags: c++, optimization, assembly

Why is returning a `std::pair` or `boost::tuple` so much less efficient than returning by reference? In real codes that I've tested, setting data by non-const reference rather than by `std::pair` in an inner kernel can speed up the code by 20%.

As an experiment, I looked at three simplest-case scenarios involving adding two (predefined) integers to two integers:

1. Use an inner, inlined function to modify the integers by reference
2. Use two inner, inlined function to return ints by value
3. Use an inner, inlined function to return a std::pair which are copied to the result.

Compiling with `g++ -c $x -Wall -Wextra -O2 -S` results in the same assembly code for passing by reference and returning ints by value:

```
__Z7getPairiRiS_:
LFB19:
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
    leal    1023(%rdi), %eax
    addl    $31, %edi
    movl    %eax, (%rsi)
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
    movl    %edi, (%rdx)
    leave
    ret
```

(Pass by reference code:

```
#include <utility>

inline void myGetPair(const int inp, int& a, int& b) {
    a = 1023 + inp;
    b = 31 + inp;
}

void getPair(const int inp, int& a, int& b) {
    myGetPair(inp, a, b);
}
```

Using individual rvalues:

```
#include <utility>

inline int myGetPair1(int inp) {
    return 1023 + inp;
}

inline int myGetPair2(int inp) {
    return 31 + inp;
}

void getPair(const int inp, int& a, int& b) {
    a = myGetPair1(inp);
    b = myGetPair2(inp);
}
```

)

Using std::pair, however, adds five extra assembly statements:

```
__Z7getPairiRiS_:
LFB18:
    leal    31(%rdi), %eax
    addl    $1023, %edi
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
    salq    $32, %rax
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
    orq %rdi, %rax
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    movl    %eax, (%rsi)
    shrq    $32, %rcx
    movl    %ecx, (%rdx)
    leave
    ret
```

The code for that is nearly as simple as the previous examples:

```
#include <utility>

inline std::pair<int,int> myGetPair(int inp) {
    return std::make_pair(1023 + inp, 31 + inp);
}

void getPair(const int inp, int& a, int& b) {
    std::pair<int,int> result = myGetPair(inp);

    a = result.first;
    b = result.second;
}
```

Can anyone who knows the inner workings of compilers help with this question? The [boost tuple page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) makes reference to a performance penalty for tuples vs. pass-by-reference, but none of the linked papers answer the question.

The reason I'd prefer std::pair to these pass-by-reference statements is that it makes the intent of the function *much* clearer in many circumstances, especially when other parameters are input as well as the ones that are to be modified.

Comment: Because you are making copies when you return by value.

Comment: When I did "inline int myGetPair2(int inp) ", it also returned by value. The compiler optimized it out. Why can't it do so when using the simple std::pair structs?

Comment: Which version of GCC is this? According to the answers, it looks like both MSVC and recent versions of GCC can  handle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried that with VC++2008, using `cl.exe /c /O2 /FAs foo.cpp` (that's "compile only and do not link", "optimize for speed", and "dump assembly output with matching source code lines in comments"). Here's what `getLine()` ended up being.

"byref" version:

```
PUBLIC  ?getPair@@YAXHAAH0@Z                ; getPair
; Function compile flags: /Ogtpy
;   COMDAT ?getPair@@YAXHAAH0@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_inp$ = 8                       ; size = 4
_a$ = 12                        ; size = 4
_b$ = 16                        ; size = 4
?getPair@@YAXHAAH0@Z PROC               ; getPair, COMDAT

; 9    :     myGetPair(inp, a, b);

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _inp$[esp-4]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _a$[esp-4]
    lea ecx, DWORD PTR [eax+1023]
    mov DWORD PTR [edx], ecx
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _b$[esp-4]
    add eax, 31                 ; 0000001fH
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx], eax

; 10   : }

    ret 0
?getPair@@YAXHAAH0@Z ENDP               ; getPair
```

"byval" `std::pair`-returning version:

```
PUBLIC  ?getPair@@YAXHAAH0@Z                ; getPair
; Function compile flags: /Ogtpy
;   COMDAT ?getPair@@YAXHAAH0@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_inp$ = 8                       ; size = 4
_a$ = 12                        ; size = 4
_b$ = 16                        ; size = 4
?getPair@@YAXHAAH0@Z PROC               ; getPair, COMDAT

; 8    :     std::pair<int,int> result = myGetPair(inp);

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _inp$[esp-4]

; 9    : 
; 10   :     a = result.first;

    mov edx, DWORD PTR _a$[esp-4]
    lea ecx, DWORD PTR [eax+1023]
    mov DWORD PTR [edx], ecx

; 11   :     b = result.second;

    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _b$[esp-4]
    add eax, 31                 ; 0000001fH
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx], eax

; 12   : }

    ret 0
?getPair@@YAXHAAH0@Z ENDP               ; getPair
```

As you can see, the actual assembly is identical; the only difference is in mangled names and comments.

Comment: Interesting; so it's therefore just an extra optimization that gcc doesn't do.

Answer (score 5):

Bad optimization. Let's hope that compilers will be better someday.

Answer (score 4):

What compiler are you using? On gcc 4.4.2 I get exactly the same result (opcode for opcode) for the pass-by-reference and the return-pairs-by-value. Namely:

```
mov 0x4(%esp),%eax
mov 0x8(%esp),%edx
lea 0x3ff(%eax),%ecx
add $0x1f,%eax
mov %ecx,(%edx)
mov 0xc(%esp),%edx
mov %eax,(%edx)
ret
lea 0x0(%esi),%esi
```

This is with `-O2 -fomit-frame-pointer`. It looks like the compiler understands the intent here and hasn't done anything redundant. Maybe you should upgrade yours :P

Answer (score 3):

Returning by value forces the construction of unnamed temporaries on the stack and the assignment of their values to your local variables.

Comment: Not true. The C++ Standard says that such temporaries may or may not be created.

Answer (score 3):

Most C++ programmers value clarity of expression far above some dubious "efficiency" issues. But if you must know, returning a reference will almost always be implemented by the compiler by returning a pointer.

Comment: My concern wasn't with returning references but with passing as a reference in place. And there is nothing dubious about a reproducible, nontrivial speed increase when returning a `std::pair` on my workhorse compiler and machine.

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly guessing, but I think that one reason the compiler has a difficulty optimizing `std::pair` is that `pair` has a non-trivial constructor. This makes it non-POD, and the compiler can't make too aggressive assumptions when optimizing.

The POD-ness rules are changing in C++0x, though, so maybe that'll help things.